# What is the proper way to pass raw pointers from a larger object to a smaller object to do something specialized with?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I'm using a C library from C++ and consequently I'm dealing with a lot of raw pointers. I want to create a pointer in an object (like `A`) and then pass the pointer to another object (like `B`) for doing something specialized with. I then want B's life to end but A to persist to do other things with the pointer.

The following code produces a `double free or corruption` error and then exits with code `139`. When I remove the destructors, however, this does not happen (which doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me since I thought any object that uses raw pointers should implement its own destructor for tidying up after itself).

Why does this happen and is there a better strategy for achieving the above?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;


struct World { // potentially containing a large amount of data
    int a;
    int b;
    const char *c;
};


class B {
private:
    World *world_;

public:
    std::string doSomethingCleverWithWorld(){
        std::ostringstream os;
        os << world_->c << " = " << world_->a + world_->b <<std::endl;
        return os.str();
    }

    explicit B(World *world) {
        world_ = world;
    }

    ~B(){
        // I want the pointer to world_ to persist after use of B
//        delete world_;
    }
};

class A {
private:
    World *world_;

public:
    explicit A(World *world) {
        world_ = world;
    }

    ~A() {
        delete world_;
    }

    A(const A &a) {
        this->world_ = a.world_;
    }

    A(A &&a) noexcept {
        this->world_ = a.world_;
    }

    A &operator=(const A &a) {
        if (this != &a) {
            this->world_ = a.world_;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    A &operator=(A &&a) noexcept {
        if (this != &a) {
            this->world_ = a.world_;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    std::string doCleverStuff(){
        B b(world_);
        return b.doSomethingCleverWithWorld();
    }

};


int main() {
    World world{
        4, 6, "stuff"
    };

    A a(&world);
    std::string clever = a.doCleverStuff();
    std::cout << clever << std::endl;

    return 0;
};
```

Output

```
stuff = 10

double free or corruption (out)

Process finished with exit code 134
```

Comment: You must only use `delete` to delete objects created with `new`. `World world;` in main is not, so you can't delete it.

Comment: So the pointer to `world_` gets cleaned up by the default destructor like any other variable not created with new?

Comment: `~A() { delete world_; }` isn't right.  `A` doesn't own the `World*` it has cached as a member variable.

Comment: @CiaranWelsh The pointer itself - yes.

Comment: Ah okay, so `main` owns `world` since that's where it was created? and its deleted when `main` goes out of scope automatically, which is why manually calling delete breaks the program.

Comment: @CiaranWelsh - World instance is created on the stack and should not be freed manually. It will get destroyed automatically with the end of the scope and destruction of the stack frame it belongs to - in this case the scope is the main() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to wrap all the comments - data can be allocated on the heap and on the stack. Allocations on the heap are done using `new` and freed using `delete` (or `malloc()` and `free()` in C; delete will call destructor and free memory and `free` will simply free memory).

When you create local variable (and your World instance is local to `main()` function) your data will be created on the stack and will live till the end of the scope it was created in - which in your case is scope of the function `main()`. You can manage only memory allocated dynamically (on the heap) and attempts to do so with memory allocated on the stack will lead to issue you've encountered.